# How to convert string to date time format Mysql

Tags: mysql, str-to-date

I have this file csv:

```
20170117-00:00:6    3087A6B282A46C  124.191.134.139 2746    256 63628   
20170117-00:00:53   330391C9F58B5A  120.18.97.172   2746    257 43077
20170117-00:02:27   3303CD14BD40C8  110.147.131.78  2746    256 63628
20170117-00:02:00   3304B3CD448E4F  189.35.218.62   2746    255 43074
```

and I am trying to upload it using load data local infile but I obtain only Null value in the time column. Here there is my code (Time is the name of the table column)

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path.log'
                INTO TABLE Clicks
                CHARACTER SET latin1
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'

                ENCLOSED BY '"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 ROWS

                SET Time= STR_TO_DATE(@Time,'%Y%m%d-%H:%i:%s')
                ;
```

Comment: `20170117-00:00:6` ... is the missing digit after the `6` a typo?

Comment: I guess `IGNORE 1 ROWS` is ment to ignore `6`, it might not be a typo

Comment: yes it is a typo (20170117-00:00:16). I omitted the first row. In the file there is the row withe the column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the syntax you should be using:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path.log'
INTO TABLE Clicks
CHARACTER SET latin1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(@Time, column2, column3, column4, column5)         -- read time data into @Time
SET column1 = STR_TO_DATE(@Time, '%Y%m%d-%H:%i:%s') -- then set column1
```

I think the `@Time` variable was never being set to anything for each record being read, hence you were getting `NULL` in the first column.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'path.log'
                INTO TABLE Clicks
                CHARACTER SET latin1
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'

                ENCLOSED BY '"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
                IGNORE 1 ROWS

                SET TIME= CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@Time,1,4),'-',SUBSTRING(@Time,5,2),'-',SUBSTRING(@Time,7,2),' ',REPLACE(@Time,CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@Time, '-',1),'-'),''))
```